# Can't save an image captured from webcam (imwrite compile error with OpenCV 2.3)

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I'm making simple webcam program using OpenCV 2.3 and got stuck by the compile error. Any idea will be appreciated.

Upon compile, I get the following error at imwrite (in read function in the code below).

[This sample](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp) that uses imwrite to save an image works on my environment, which indicates imwrite in OpenCV 2.3 should work on my env.

error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const cv::_InputArray&’ from expression of type ‘cv::Mat*’
/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp:110: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘bool cv::imwrite(const std::string&, const cv::_InputArray&, const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’
```

code excerpt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//IplImage* SampleClassA::dispImg = NULL;
Mat* SampleClassA::dispImg = NULL;

int read()
{
        Mat* sharedImg;
    sharedImg = getFrame();
    if (sharedImg)
    {
        if (dispImg == NULL)
        {
            SampleClassA::dispImg = sharedImg;
        }
        Mat outMat;
        outMat = imwrite("./out/sample.jpg", sharedImg);
    }
    sleep(100);
    return 1;
}

Mat* getFrame()
//IplImage* ReadRealTime::getFrame()
{
    if (!capture.isOpened()) // Actual capturing part is omitted here.
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    Mat frame;
    capture >> frame;
    return &frame;
}
</code>
```

Btw, I'm confused whether imwrite takes 2 arguments or 3. Both the following link and highgui.hpp on my machine say 3 args, but the sample code I cited above ([from ros.org](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp)) uses only 2 (which is because I'm doing the same).
http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite

ps. Forgive my posting the same question here with the one I sent to OpenCV@yahoogroups.com if you are subscribing to it. The reason I did this is because this website seems more interactive and convenient for various purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third param is optional (array of format dependent parameters).
The error you are getting is because 'sharedImage' is of type Mat* that can't cast automatically to 'const cv::_InputArray&', the expected type for imwrite. If look at the example more carefully, you'll see that the type of the parameter passed in as second is actually a 'Mat' (not a Mat*).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @crisbia. Now after seeing your comment, I just worked around the compile error by adding '*' in front of sharedImg (that makes *sharedImg) for the 2nd arg of imwrite. Don't know if it works as I originally expect (I'm still kinda new to pointers) but hoping it's good for now.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: @user577: you shouldn't be using pointers at all there. Mat is a reference-counted datatype. Your code is broken, you are returning a pointer to a local variable (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).