# Crash during running at cvCopyImage/cvResize

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, stack, runtime-error

I'm making simple webcam program using OpenCV 2.3 and got stuck by the runtime error. Any idea will be appreciated.

Compile passes but upon running, I get the following error (at cvCopyImage/cvResize in 'read' function in the code below).

error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /usr/local/src/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.3.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 641
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /usr/local/src/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.3.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:641: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat
```

code excerpt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat* SampleClassA::dispImg = NULL;

int read()
{
    Mat* sharedImg;
    sharedImg = getFrame();
    if (sharedImg)
    {
        if (dispImg == NULL)
        {
            SampleClassA::dispImg = sharedImg;
        }
    cvCopyImage(sharedImg, SampleClassA::dispImg); // Crashes here.
    cvResize(sharedImg, SampleClassA::classifyImg); // Can crash here too when cvCopyImage is commented out.
    }
    sleep(100);
    return 1;
}

Mat* getFrame()
//IplImage* ReadRealTime::getFrame()
{
    if (!capture.isOpened()) // Actual capturing part is omitted here.
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    Mat frame;
    capture >> frame;
    return &frame;
}
</code>
```

My guess is there's something wrong either/both in the way I use Mat, or pointer. I'm still new both to OpenCV and C/C++ pointer (I've got an insightful comment in another question [Can't save an image captured from webcam (imwrite compile error with OpenCV 2.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783534/cant-save-an-image-captured-from-webcam-imwrite-compile-error-with-opencv-2-3) to point out possible "dangling pointer", but is this time the same?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning a pointer to a stack allocated variable, which is automatically destroyed at the end of the function.

```
  // ...
  Mat frame;
  capture >> frame;
  return &frame;
} // frame destroyed is at the end of the function yet you return a pointer to it!
```

You need to allocate the frame on the heap so that it will live on past the end of the function:

```
  // ...
  Mat* frame = new Mat(); // Maybe this needs parameters
  capture >> *frame;
  return frame;
}
```

Remember that you need to `delete` the frame at a later point or your application will leak memory.